# How to put a button on the bottom of the div and under and image?

Tags: html, css

So, this is a small problem, with probably a small solution that my brain apparently cannot figure out.

HTML:

```css
#div {
    position: fixed;
    top: 10%;
    left: 20%;
    right: 20%;
    bottom: 10%;
    z-index: 999;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="div">
  <h1>Settings</h1>
  <center>
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOhGp.png" style="width: 30px; margin-bottom: -8px;"><br/>
    <button style="float: bottom; position: absolute; bottom: 10px;">Hide</button>
  </center>
</div>
```

Apparently, the button gets stuck on the right part of the screen. However, I want it to be in the middle just like the image on the top. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove style from `button` and add `margin-top`

```css
#div {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10%;
  left: 20%;
  right: 20%;
  bottom: 10%;
  z-index: 999;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#div button {
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="div">
  <h1>Settings</h1>
  <center>
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOhGp.png" style="width: 30px; margin-bottom: -8px;"><br/>
    <button>Hide</button>
  </center>
</div>
```

```css
#div {
    position: fixed;
    top: 10%;
    left: 20%;
    right: 20%;
    bottom: 10%;
    z-index: 999;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="div">
  <h1>Settings</h1>
  <center>
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOhGp.png" style="width: 30px; margin-bottom: -8px;"><br/>
    <button style="float: bottom; position: absolute; bottom: 10px;">Hide</button>
  </center>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Update `style` of the `button` `style="margin-top: 15px;"`

```css
#div {
    position: fixed;
    top: 10%;
    left: 20%;
    right: 20%;
    bottom: 10%;
    z-index: 999;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="div">
  <h1>Settings</h1>
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOhGp.png" style="width: 30px; margin-bottom: -8px;"><br/>
    <button style="margin-top: 15px;">Hide</button>
</div>
```